create new array by compare two arrays in react without affecting existing
I have DataArray1 and DataArray2 , by comparing both i try to create new array without affect existing one (DataArray1)
DataArray1 = [
{
 id :'1",
 name : "sachin",
 age: "23",
 addre :"xyz",
 amount: '78',
},
{
 id :'2",
 name : "rahul",
 age: "12",
 addre :"xyz",
 amount: '23',
},
{
 id :'3",
 name : "messi",
 age: "34",
 addre :"xyz",
  amount: '230',
},
{
 id :'4",
 name : "vinay",
 age: "16",
 addre :"xyz",
  amount: '67',
}


DataArray2 = [
{
 id :'4",
 mobile : "12121" 
},
{
 id :'1",
mobile : "3434" 
}

comparing id of the both array and changed amount and pushed into new array without affecting exisintg DataArray1
 if(DataArray1 && DataArray1?.length > 0 && DataArray2 && DataArray2?.length > 0) {   
          newData = DataArray1.forEach(item => {
              const matchingData = DataArray2.find(
                siteDataObj => item.id === siteDataObj.id
              );
              if (matchingData) {
                item.amount = 0; 
              } else {
                item.amount = 100; 
              } 
            });  
            
            
            }

setNewdata(newData); 

But in this code existing DataArray1  still affecting with new amount value.
Expected result :
result = [
{
 id :'1",
 name : "sachin",
 age: "23",
 addre :"xyz",
 amount: '100',
},
{
 id :'2",
 name : "rahul",
 age: "12",
 addre :"xyz",
 amount: '0',
},
{
 id :'3",
 name : "messi",
 age: "34",
 addre :"xyz",
  amount: '0',
},
{
 id :'4",
 name : "vinay",
 age: "16",
 addre :"xyz",
  amount: '100',
}


You can map array 1 and array 2 as you did in forEach. Then, return newly created elements without changing the array1 or array2 elements. Use ...(Spread syntax) to get all fields in the object and then set the amount manually according to the matchingData


const DataArray1 = [
{
 id :"1",
 name : "sachin",
 age: "23",
 addre :"xyz",
 amount: "78",
},
{
 id :"2",
 name : "rahul",
 age: "12",
 addre :"xyz",
 amount: '23',
},
{
 id :"3",
 name : "messi",
 age: "34",
 addre :"xyz",
  amount: '230',
},
{
 id :"4",
 name : "vinay",
 age: "16",
 addre :"xyz",
  amount: '67',
}];

const DataArray2 = [
{
 id :"4",
 mobile : "12121" 
},
{
 id :"1",
mobile : "3434" 
}];

const newData = DataArray1.map(item => {
    const matchingData = DataArray2.some(
        siteDataObj => item.id === siteDataObj.id
    );
              
    return {
        ...item,
        amount: matchingData ? 100 : 0
    };
}); 

// setNewdata(newData);

console.log("Output:", newData);
console.log("DataArray1:", DataArray1);



Hope, it's clear and helpful

If I understand correctly, you want to check if there are any items in DataArray1 that are equal to any corresponding items in another array. If there's a match, the amount should be set to 100; otherwise, it should be set to 0. If that's the case, you could begin by extracting all keys from the second list and putting them into a new list:
const DataArray2Keys = DataArray2.map(d => d.id);

then using map achieve a new list of item:
const updatedArr = DataArray1.map((d) => DataArray2Keys.includes(d.id) ? ({...d, amount: 100}) : ({...d, amount: 0}))

on map we loop through all item in the first array and check whether we have such id into the second one or not, if we have, we return a new object and adjust the amount.
the problem with your code snippet is you are mutating your object inside the array.

This might help you


const DataArray1 = [
{
id :"1",
name : "sachin",
age: "23",
addre :"xyz",
amount: '78',
},
{
id : "2",
name : "rahul",
age: "12",
addre :"xyz",
amount: '23',
},
{
id :"3",
name : "messi",
age: "34",
addre :"xyz",
 amount: '230',
},
{
id :"4",
name : "vinay",
age: "16",
addre :"xyz",
 amount: '67',
}
]


const DataArray2 = [
{
id :"4",
mobile : "12121" 
},
{
id :"1",
mobile : "3434" 
}
]

const newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(DataArray1));

const setNewData = () => {
 if(DataArray1 && DataArray1?.length > 0 && DataArray2 && DataArray2?.length > 0) {
    DataArray1.forEach((item, index) => {
     const matchingData = DataArray2.find(
               siteDataObj => item.id === siteDataObj.id
             )
       if (matchingData) {
         newData[index].amount = '0'; 
       } else {
         newData[index].amount = '100'; 
       }
     });
     }
}
setNewData();

console.log("DataArray1", DataArray1);
console.log("newData", newData);




asnwers with comments like "use this", "this might help you" or no explanation at all are considered bad answers, event if they are correct and they help solve the issue. Please add details of what you did and how does this help fix the issue for the OP

You are directly modifying the values in DataArray1. When you iterate over each item in DataArray1 and then are setting the item to 0 or 100 when you call
item.amount = 

Also, foreach does not return a new array. It just modifies the existing. If you just want to return a new array, you can use .map(). Instead of setting item.amount, you could copy the item and return a modified copy of the item. Something like this:
const newData = DataArray1.map(item => {
   const matchingData = DataArray2.find(siteDataObj => item.id === siteDataObj.id);
   let newAmount;
   if(matchingData) {
     newAmount = 0;
   } else {
     newAmount = 100;
   }
   return {...item, amount: newAmount} <-- The ... is a spread operator and it copies the object. 
});

Just to note, in your expected result, you say you are expecting the entries with id 1 and 4 to have amount of 100. But in your code, if you find a match you set the amount to 0. So either the expected result is wrong, or you need to switch your code and set the amount to 100 if you find a match.
